# how to make jquery run only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have the following code which gives me the id of an element when I click on it. I want this just give me one element's id when I click on it and not when I click on the second element.

```
$("svg").click(function() {
    if(this.id!='main_svg') {
        divs[1]=this.id;
    }
});
```

I was thinking on using a flag variable with an if condition but I want to know if there's a better solution to this than the one below

```
Var flag = 0;
if($flag==0){
    $("svg").click(function() {
        if(this.id!='main_svg') {
            alert("second.one "+this.id); 
            divs[1]=this.id;
            flag=1;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("svg").one("click", function() {
  if(this.id!='main_svg')   {
  divs[1]=this.id;
 }
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution I think, for your question

Answer (score 0):

You can unregister the click handler after it has been used.

See http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

EDIT: It appears your question should be reworded to "how to make jquery run for specific element", in order to make it run for one element's id, change your selector from `$("svg")` to `$("#main_svg")`

Answer (score 0):

**Explicitly removing the event handler through `off()`**

Generally, you can remove an event handler after via the [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function, which in your case would be handled after it was initially called :

```
$("svg").click(function() {
   if(this.id != 'main_svg')   {
      divs[1]=this.id;
   }
   // Kill event handler here
   $('svg').off('click');
});
```

**Using `:one()` to ensure at most a single execution**

A preferred approach might be to consider using the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function, which is specifically designed to handle just this scenario :

> **one()**: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

which would be used as :

```
$("svg").one("click", function() {
     if(this.id!='main_svg'){ divs[1]=this.id; }
});
```